# I want to display some products using an object array in C#

Tags: c#, arrayobject

I have a class

```
public class Product
{
    private long id;   
    private String name;  
    private String internCode;  
    private String producer;// 

    public long Id { get => id; set => id = value; }
    public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
    public string InternCode { get => internCode; set => internCode = value; }
    public string Producer { get => producer; set => producer = value; }

    public void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Products: " +Id+"  "+Name + "[" +InternCode + "] " + Producer);
    }
}
```

and this is Program class

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Product prod1 = new Product();
        Product prod2 = new Product();
        Console.WriteLine("The Id for the first product is:");
        prod1.Id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("The name of the first product is:");
        prod1.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The Intern Code is:");
        prod1.InternCode = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The producer is:");
        prod1.Producer = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The Id for the second product is:");
        prod2.Id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("The name for the second product is:");
        prod2.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        while (prod2.Name == prod1.Name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This product has already been introduced. Please introduce a new product:");
            prod2.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The intern code is:");
        prod2.InternCode = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The producer is:");
        prod2.Producer = Console.ReadLine();


        Console.WriteLine("The products are:");
        Console.WriteLine();
        prod1.display();
        Console.WriteLine();
        prod2.display();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();            
    }
```

I want to read the products by user input and display them using an object array, Product[] array1=new Product[] , instead of using prod1 and prod2 objects.
Please give me any example or any link to document me how to solve this.Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need an **array**?  In most cases, a `List<Product>` would be used instead.  Then you can simply use [List.Add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of having to resize and copy your array whenever it needs to be resized...

Comment: I would prefer to use an array because it says in the problem indication. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: @Idle_Mind Well yes though it adds a great deal of convenience but `List<T>` essentially an array implementation (I mean a dynamic array implementation)

Comment: This is a little off-topic and more 'code review', but for future reference you can put "\n" (without quotes) at the start or end of your parameters for Console.WriteLine() to get the extra lines, and cut down on clutter.

Comment: @Rahul true, but you don't have to resize it yourself with a List.

Comment: `Please give me any example or any link to document` If the NET documentation is not on your most used list, it ought to be [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/)

Comment: @Idle_Mind that's why said *great convenience* :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Product
{
    public long Id {get; set;}   
    public String Name {get; set;}  
    public String InternCode {get; set;}  
    public String producer {get; set;}

    public overrides string ToString()
    {
        return $"Products: {Id}  {Name}[{InternCode}] {Producer}";
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var products = new List<Product>();

    bool again = true;
    while(again)
    {
        var product = new Product();
        Console.WriteLine("The Id for the first product is:");
        product.Id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("The name of the first product is:");
        product.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The Intern Code is:");
        product.InternCode = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The producer is:");
        product.Producer = Console.ReadLine();
        products.Add(product);

        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter another product (y/n)?");
        again = (Console.ReadKey(true).Key.ToString().ToLower() == "y");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nThe products are:");
    foreach(var product in products)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(product);
    }
    Console.ReadKey(true);            
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use a List because you have an Add method to add new products. To check if a product exists you can use Linq's Any extension of IEnumerable:

```
var products = new List<Product>();
...
while (!lastuserinput.Equals("exit"))
{    
    var productName = Console.ReadLine(); 
    if (products.Any(product=>product.Name.Equals(productName))
    {
       Console.WriteLine("product already exists");
       continue;
    }
    ...
    productList.Add(new Product
    {
        ...
        Name = productName,
        ...
    };
...
}
```